# Galois group of $x^6+1$

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

$x^6+1$ has $6$ roots: $i,i\xi,i\xi^2,i\xi^3,i\xi^4,i\xi^5$ where $\xi=e^{\tfrac{2\pi i}{6}}$. Since $x^{12}-1=(x^6-1)(x^6+1)$ the splitting field of $x^{12}-1$ contains the splitting field of $x^6+1$ and therefore the degree of the splitting field of $x^6+1$ must be $4$ or $2$. Can anyone help me out here whether the degree is 4 or 2?

Comment: Can you show that the splitting field is $\Bbb{Q}(i,\xi^2)$? You have surely seen $\xi^2$ before.

Comment: it is $x^6+1=(x^3+i)(x^3-i)$ Therefore the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(i,\xi^2)$. The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $2$. to show that  $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\xi^2):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ (what i am assuming) i still need to show that $\xi^2$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. How can i do that?

Comment: $\xi^2$ is a primitive third root of unity. You know, the one with $i\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: that $\xi^2$ is a primitive third root of unity is clear to me what you mean by "the one with $i\sqrt{3}$" not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The splitting field of $ x^{12}-1 $  is the same as the splitting field of $x^6+1$. Actually, it is the $12$-th cyclotomic field and its degree is $\varphi(12)=4$.

The minimal polynomial is easy to find with simple high school formulae:
$$x^6+1=(x^2)^3+1=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)$$
A generator of the splitting field is  $\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}{6}}$ thus has minimal polynomial: $\, x^4-x^2+1$. (We check its factorisation in $\mathrm R[x]$ is $(x^2-\sqrt3x+1)(x^2+\sqrt3x+1)$, hence it is irreducible over $\mathrm Q$).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Still dont understand why "The splitting field of $x^{12}−1$ is the same as the splitting field of $x^6+1$." in that case it as you said is easy to proof that the degree of the splitting field of $x^6+1$ is $4$-

Comment: It is the same because it is contained in it (the reverse inclusion is trivial): $\,\zeta=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}{6}}$ has order $12$, hence all $12$-th  roots of unity are powers of $\zeta$.

Comment: Okay see where you are going but how do you know that $e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{6}}$ is a generator of the splitting field $x^6+1$?

Comment: Because the six roots of this polynomial are its odd powers (1, 3, 5, 7, 9,11).

Comment: You showed that these six roots are in $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{6}})$, but how can i be sure that there is not an alpha generating these six roots, but not generating the even powers, so that $\mathbb{Q}(e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{6}}) \supsetneq \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. So $\alpha$ would also be a generator of the splitting field $x^6+1$. So I dont know why this splitting field generated by $e^{\tfrac{i\pi}{6}}$ is "minimal".

Comment: But if α generates these roots, it generates in particular $\,\mathrm e ^{ \tfrac{\mathrm i \pi}{6}}$, and your inclusion can't be strict. Another reason why it's minimal, is that it has degree $4$. A strict subextension would have degree $2$, and it's impossible, due to the minimal polynomial of  $\,\mathrm e ^{ \tfrac{\mathrm i \pi}{6}}$.